# How to open an image and have it print?

Tags: javascript, html, image, window

So I have the code shown below and I want the image to open in a new tab and print right away. But i can't seem to get that too work. Any help is appreciated.

```
function Print(){
     window.open('images/couponPrintSmall.jpg');
     window.onLoad = window.print();
}
```

Comment: What is calling `Print()`?

Comment: a paragraph is calling print()

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
function Print(){
     var win = window.open('images/couponPrintSmall.jpg' , "win");
     win.onload = win.print;
}
```

Actually , this one works:

```
function Print(){
    var win = window.open('' );
    var img=win.document.createElement("img");
    img.src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schoolslogoNEW310113.gif";
    win.document.body.appendChild(img);
    img.onload = function(){ 
        win.print();
    };  
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qPYw6/7/

Comment: still not working, like i said above a paragraph is calling the print function

Comment: @user2489995 what it means `paragraph is calling`? Some `p` tag calling javascript function? By clicking on it?

Comment: when you say it isn't working, are you seeing the window open but not print or does the window not open? Is the window blocked by a popup blocker.

Comment: no the window opens, but instead of printing the new page it prints the already open one.

Comment: actually its not printing at all now

Comment: @lemieuxster so a p tag is calling the function win onclick and the printing just doesnt seem to happen.

Comment: your code worked till I changed the w3c schools url to my url;

Comment: could it make a difference that i am not testing it through a local server

Comment: @user2489995 you can edit my jsfiddle with your image' url and send me a link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qPYw6/9/ but I doubt that will work. You can't test an image that is on my side

Comment: @user2489995 so put it on some free hosting

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the best fix for this problem is simply to link the text to a separate page. And then in the body put a onLoad = window.print(). It was much easier, and I figured I would answer my own question seeing it still had no correct answer.